# ffmpeg av_seek_frame

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am attempting to seek in a movie using ffmpeg's av_seek_frame method however I'm having the most trouble determining how to generate a time-stamp to seek to.  Assuming I want to seek x amount of frames either forward or backward and I know what frame the movie is currently on, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Couldn't you calculate the time offset using the frame rate?

Comment: From what I understand, the time offset needs to be in time_base units but I'm not exactly sure how to convert it to those units (or even if that's what I need to be doing).  If that is what I need to do, I'm not sure what the units of time_base are in (seconds, frames, frames per second).

Answer (score 19):

Here is how i did it:

```
// Duration of one frame in AV_TIME_BASE units
int64_t timeBase;

void open(const char* fpath){
    ...
    timeBase = (int64_t(pCodecCtx->time_base.num) * AV_TIME_BASE) / int64_t(pCodecCtx->time_base.den);
    ...
}

bool seek(int frameIndex){

    if(!pFormatCtx)
        return false;

    int64_t seekTarget = int64_t(frameIndex) * timeBase;

    if(av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, -1, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY) < 0)
        mexErrMsgTxt("av_seek_frame failed.");

}
```

The AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY enables seeking to every frame and not just keyframes.

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer: You should have an AVFormatContext object lying around. Its `duration` property tells you how long your file is in terms of the time-stamp multiplied by 1000 that can be used in av_seek_frame, so treat it as 100%. Then you can calculate how far into the video you want to seek to.

if you want to go forward one frame, simply call av_read_frame and avcodec_decode_video  until it fills the got_picture_ptr with a non-zero value. Before calling avcodec_decode_video make sure the packet from av_read_frame is from the video stream. avcodec_decode_video will then fill in the AVFrame structure which you can use to do anything with.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is super accurate, but the following is very simple and seems to work:

```c
int n_seconds = 10; // seek forward 10 seconds
// time_base is in seconds, eg. the time base may be 1/1000th of a second,
// so just multiply by the reciprocal (den = denominator, num = numerator)
int64_t ts = av_rescale(
    n_seconds,
    format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->time_base.den,
    format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->time_base.num
);
// even though it mentions in docs that you shouldn't use this because it is a
// work in progress, it's been around for more than a decade now, ffplay/ffmpeg/ffprobe
// all use it...it is the most consistent and easiest to use. the way I am using
// it here is to seek to the nearest keyframe (not frame!). I would not recommend
// using it in any other way:
// eg. AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY/FRAME/BACKWARD (BACKWARD is ignored anyways)
// 0 as flag seeks to keyframes only. I have set the max timestamp to the same value so
// that we only look for nearest keyframes behind us
int err = avformat_seek_file(pFormatContext, video_stream_index, 0, ts, ts, 0);
```

This seeks to the nearest keyframe! Which could be pretty far from you want. However, it will only ever be behind the target timestamp, so you can just `av_read_frame` until you get to where you want, using `AVframe->pts` * `AVStream->timebase` to calculate what time the frame is (use `av_rescale` to do this).

Also note that if you need to seek backward (that is a frame behind one you already read with `av_read_frame`) or you are going to be calling `av_read_frame` more than once on a frame in general, you have to send/receive the packet/frame with `avcodec_send_packet` and `avcodec_receive_frame` respectively, otherwise the codec context will be out of sync (I think that's the issue?). You can't just read packets blankly. You also should `avcodec_flush_buffers` after you seek to a new location that's behind where you were reading from (you should probably just call it every time you seek, but I am not sure about performance).

Doc reference:

[int avformat_seek_file (..., int stream_index, int64_t min_ts, int64_t ts, int64_t max_ts, int flags)](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga3b40fc8d2fda6992ae6ea2567d71ba30)

Comment: Thank you! Found that to reset to the beginning of the stream takes actually 3 steps, like
avcodec_send_packet(video_dec_ctx, NULL) + av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, video_stream_idx, 0, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY) +avcodec_flush_buffers(video_dec_ctx);