# av_seek_frame seek only every 12th frames

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg video player in my graphic aps.

Now I need to implement correct way to start video with specific frame (not only with first). I found good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504792/ffmpeg-av-seek-frame) and at first thought, that it works for me perfectly:

```
    bool seek(uint64_t frame)
    {
        int64_t timeBase = (static_cast<int64_t>(_pContext->time_base.num) * AV_TIME_BASE)
                    / static_cast<int64_t>(_pContext->time_base.den);
        auto seekTarget = static_cast<int64_t>(frame) * timeBase;

        if( av_seek_frame(_pFile, -1, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY) < 0)
            return false;

        avcodec_flush_buffers( _pContext );
        return true;
    }
```

However, lately I noticed that it seeks only every 12th frame:

```
seek(10); //gives 0 frame
seek(12); //gives 12 frame
seek(20); //gives 12 frame
seek(80); //gives 72 frame
```

I guess I calculate `timeBase` incorrectly, but actually I can't find inforamation how to do it in correct way. There are plenty of code examples, but I've tried many of them and it didn't work at all. It's even weired, that I found too many different ways to calculate the same variable.

P.S. It would be great if someone explain me the meaning of timeBase value, or share good explanation.

Comment: The `av_seek_frame` seeks to the keyframes.

Comment: It depends on flag AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY/AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME, it's it?

Comment: Is the source seekable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to seek to the previous key frame and decode until you have the frame that you want. You can't seek to ANY frame as the decoder will not decode properly the requested frame.

You can find a detailed discussion and code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397968/how-to-get-currecnt-avframe-siquential-number-after-av-seek-frame/67404457#67404457)